# How to wait for Expect 100-continue response in Java using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection, legacy

I am **stuck** using HttpURLConnection to make a PUT http request to a web-server. I have some code that will make a PUT request just fine, and I can trivially include the 'Expect 100-continue Request Property' in the headers however try as I might I can't seem to make the function wait for the '100 Continue' response from the server before sending the actual http payload.

I get the following (from Wireshark)

```
PUT /post/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Expect: 100-continue
Host: somerandomdomain.info
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 17

Some data for you
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

...rest of web-server response...
```

I'm sure I am missing something obvious however after googling I have drawn a blank - can anyone help?

Many thanks if so :)

Http PUT code snippet below:

```
String url =   "http://somerandomdomain.info";
String postJsonData = "Some data for you\n";
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

// Setting basic post request  
con.setRequestMethod("PUT");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "jcurl/7.35.0");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", postData.length() + "");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
con.setRequestProperty("Expect", "100-continue");

// Send post request  
con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(postData);
wr.flush();
wr.close();

int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
System.out.println("Post Data : " + postData);
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String output;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((output = in.readLine()) != null) {
  response.append(output);
}

in.close();

//printing result from response  
System.out.println(response.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not obvious to me why they designed it this way, but the code that implements the Expect:100 logic is only used if you have called one of [`setFixedLengthStreamingMode(int contentlen)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFixedLengthStreamingMode-int-) or [the overload for `long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFixedLengthStreamingMode-long-) or [`setChunkedStreamingMode(int chunklen)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setChunkedStreamingMode-int-) before doing `getOutputStream`. In this case I recommend the first as simplest.

Comment: Java sets the Content-length header itself if neither of these methods is used, ignoring whatever the user may specify via `setRequestProperty("Content-length", ...)`; doesn't know the content length in this case until everything has been written by the application (to a hidden `ByteArrayOutputStream`); and therefore the wait could only occur after the application had closed the output stream. Maybe they felt that allowing an arbitrarily long sequence of writes to a BAOS that was maybe going to be rejected by the server when eventually attempted was a bit on the futile side.

Comment: Can you please give some more detail? In order to e.g. STOP the HTTP PUT if the server replies "sorry, you cannot continue," what do you have to do? Does HttpURLConnection automatically add the `Expect: 100-continue` header, or is that up to your application? If your application must do it, where does HttpURLConnection take over? Or does it not take over, and the client code must do something specific?