# preemptive authentication using gss/kerberos authentication in java

Tags: java, authentication, apache-httpclient-4.x

As I understand, the current java.net.URL handshake (for a GSS/Kerberos authentication mode) always entails a 401 as a first leg operation, which is kind of inefficient if we know the client and server are going to use GSS/Kerberos, right? Does anyone know if preemptive authentication (where you can present the token upfront like in the python one https://github.com/requests/requests-kerberos#preemptive-authentication) is available in the java world?

A quick google points towards https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html but the preemptive example seems to be for the Basic scheme alone.

Thanks!

Comment: IMHO the real efficiency issue is not in the *initial* handshake -- if it's just done once per session. In the Hadoop ecosystem, for example, UIs and REST services use SPNego to establish the session, then generate a session "token" that is stored in a signed cookie and presented automatically in later requests *(with one exception, where the "token" has to be requested explicitly then presented explicitly in the URL itself -- legacy stuff)*.

Comment: By the way, you should read the section labeled _'Why not use Apache HTTP Components?"_ in https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/web_and_rest.html

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter As noted by the HTTP protocol, the handshake needs to be done for every connection, and any token per session scheme is a way to optimize over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much investigation, it looks like preemptive kerberos authentication is not available in the default Hotspot java implementation. The http-components from Apache is also not able to help with this.

However, the default implementation does have the ability to only send headers when the payload is potentially large as noted in the [Expect Header and 100-Continue response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.1.1) section. To enable this, we need to use [the fixed length streaming mode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFixedLengthStreamingMode-int-) ([or other similar means](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41710065/874076)). But as noted in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFixedLengthStreamingMode-int-), authentication and redirection cannot be handled automatically - we are again back to the original problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue and came to the same conclusion as you - preemptive SPNEGO authentication is not supported neither in Oracle JRE HttpUrlConnection nor in Apache HTTP Components. I haven't checked other HTTP clients but almost sure that it should be the same.

I started working on an alternative Spnego client which can be used with any HTTP client - it's called [Kerb4J](https://github.com/bedrin/kerb4j)

You can use it like this:

```
SpnegoClient spnegoClient = SpnegoClient.loginWithKeyTab("clientPrincipal", "C:/kerberos/clientPrincipal.keytab");
URL url = new URL("http://kerberized.service/helloworld");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection;

SpnegoContext context = spnegoClient.createContext(url);

huc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", context.createTokenAsAuthroizationHeader());

// Optional mutual authentication step
String challenge = huc.getHeaderField("WWW-Authenticate").substring("Negotiate ".length());
byte[] decode = Base64.getDecoder().decode(challenge);
context.processMutualAuthorization(decode, 0, decode.length);
```

Comment: Apache projects will not be able to depend on your library directly due to license incompatibility. Please consider contributing your code to an ASLv2 licensed open-source project. I'll happily drop existing SPNEGO implementation in HttpClient favor of something better.

Comment: @oleg I would love to but currently Kerb4J is based on some source code from another projects (Mostly http://spnego.sourceforge.net/ and http://jaaslounge.sourceforge.net/) which are licensed under LGPL. I still need to rewrite some of the code before I can change the license to a more friendly one

Comment: Fair enough. The offer still stands, though. If you manage to change the license of your work to ASLv2 you are welcome to contribute it to Apache HttpComponents

Answer (score 0):

The following example shows how you can do preemptive spnego login that uses a custom entry in the login.conf. This completely bypasses the AuthScheme stuff and does all the work of generating the "authorization" header.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.ietf.jgss.GSSContext;
import org.ietf.jgss.GSSCredential;
import org.ietf.jgss.GSSException;
import org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager;
import org.ietf.jgss.GSSName;
import org.ietf.jgss.Oid;

import javax.security.auth.Subject;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction;
import java.util.Base64;

public class AsyncHttpSpnego {

  public static final String SPNEGO_OID = "1.3.6.1.5.5.2";
  private static final String KERBEROS_OID = "1.2.840.113554.1.2.2";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

    String host = inetAddress.getHostName().toUpperCase();

    System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", new File(host + "-krb5.ini").getCanonicalPath());
    System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");
    System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", new File(host + "-login.conf").getCanonicalPath());
    LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("anotherentry");
    lc.login();
    byte[] token = new byte[0];

    token = getAuthToken(host, lc, token);

    String authorizationHeader = "Negotiate" + " " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(token);

    System.out.println("Next Authorization header: " + authorizationHeader);

    CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClient = HttpClients.createMinimal();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://" + host + ":81/nick.txt");
    httpget.setHeader("Authorization", authorizationHeader);
    CloseableHttpResponse closeableHttpResponse = closeableHttpClient.execute(httpget);
    try {
      System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(closeableHttpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
    } finally {
      closeableHttpResponse.close();
    }
  }

  private static byte[] getAuthToken(String host, LoginContext lc, byte[] inToken) throws GSSException, java.security.PrivilegedActionException {
    Oid negotiationOid = new Oid(SPNEGO_OID);

    GSSManager manager = GSSManager.getInstance();
    final PrivilegedExceptionAction<GSSCredential> action = () -> manager.createCredential(null,
        GSSCredential.INDEFINITE_LIFETIME, negotiationOid, GSSCredential.INITIATE_AND_ACCEPT);

    boolean tryKerberos = false;
    GSSContext gssContext = null;
    try {
      GSSName serverName = manager.createName("HTTP@" + host, GSSName.NT_HOSTBASED_SERVICE);
      gssContext = manager.createContext(serverName.canonicalize(negotiationOid), negotiationOid, Subject.doAs(lc.getSubject(), action),
          GSSContext.DEFAULT_LIFETIME);
      gssContext.requestMutualAuth(true);
      gssContext.requestCredDeleg(true);
    } catch (GSSException ex) {
      if (ex.getMajor() == GSSException.BAD_MECH) {
        System.out.println("GSSException BAD_MECH, retry with Kerberos MECH");
        tryKerberos = true;
      } else {
        throw ex;
      }
    }
    if (tryKerberos) {
      Oid kerbOid = new Oid(KERBEROS_OID);
      GSSName serverName = manager.createName("HTTP@" + host, GSSName.NT_HOSTBASED_SERVICE);
      gssContext = manager.createContext(serverName.canonicalize(kerbOid), kerbOid, Subject.doAs(lc.getSubject(), action),
          GSSContext.DEFAULT_LIFETIME);
      gssContext.requestMutualAuth(true);
      gssContext.requestCredDeleg(true);
    }

    return gssContext.initSecContext(inToken, 0, inToken.length);
  }
}
```