# HttpUrlConnection Expect-100 Broken Pipe

Tags: java, android, http, httpurlconnection

I use a Expect 100-continue in the http header like you see in the code below.   The HttpUrlConnection when i get the outputstream dont wait the answer of the 100 Expectation or any other 400 error. (In the RFC they tell it's not a problem: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.1.1).

I've looked at this post: [How to wait for Expect 100-continue response in Java using HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41707775/how-to-wait-for-expect-100-continue-response-in-java-using-httpurlconnection) in case they have more info on the problem but i have tested the setChuncked method just to see if it's make a difference but no.

The problem is when the server answer with an error and close the connection without let me finish the upload i have a Broken Pipe Exception. It's right i write bytes on a close connection but i can't handle that correctly. I can't read the server answer. I can't know that the connection is close before the write. If i try to get the ErrorStream i get a null reference same for the InputStream, ResponseCode and other methods to know what happen.

Any idea how can make it right or what i miss to make it work?

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x73de8c02c0: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_write(Native Method)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLOutputStream.write(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:824)
at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:76)
at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:155)
at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:176)
at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:46)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$ChunkedSink.write(HttpConnection.java:339)
at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:176)
at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink$1.write(RealBufferedSink.java:198)
at out.write(buffer, 0, bytes_read);
```

In the code below, i've remove some not useful part like a global try on this, or compute for the fileSize.

```
huc = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(upload_url).openConnection();
huc.setRequestMethod("POST");
huc.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + FILE_SZ);
huc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "UA");
huc.setRequestProperty("Expect","100-continue");


huc.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(FILE_SZ);
huc.setUseCaches(false);
huc.setDoInput(true);
huc.setDoOutput(true);
huc.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
try {
   // read input file chunks + publish progress
   OutputStream out = new OutputStream(huc.getOutputStream());
   buffer_size = 4 * 1024;
   buffer = new byte[buffer_size];
   total_bytes = 0;
   while ((bytes_read = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, bytes_read);
        total_bytes += bytes_read;
   }
   out.flush();
   out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```