# HttpURLConnection : Why is there 5 seconds delay with every chunk when Expect:100-Continue Header is specified?

Tags: java, http, sockets, chunked-encoding

I am experimenting with [RFC Expect](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-5.1.1) Header in java [HttpURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html?msclkid=a043c46ca54f11ecaff177aff4f8c62f) which works perfectly except for one detail.

There is an 5 second wait period between sending the body of an [Fixed Length Mode](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html?msclkid=a043c46ca54f11ecaff177aff4f8c62f#setFixedLengthStreamingMode(int)) or between each chunk in [Chunk Streaming Mode](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html?msclkid=a043c46ca54f11ecaff177aff4f8c62f#setChunkedStreamingMode(int))

Here is the client class

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
 {
   HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection)new URL("http://192.168.1.2:2000/ActionG").openConnection();
   
   //for 100-Continue logic
   con.setRequestMethod("POST");
   con.setRequestProperty("Expect", "100-Continue");
  
   //responds to 100-continue logic
   con.setDoOutput(true);
   con.setChunkedStreamingMode(5);
   con.getOutputStream().write("Hello".getBytes());
   con.getOutputStream().flush();
   con.getOutputStream().write("World".getBytes());
   con.getOutputStream().flush();
   con.getOutputStream().write("123".getBytes());
   con.getOutputStream().flush();

   //decode response and response body/error if any
   System.out.println(con.getResponseCode()+"/"+con.getResponseMessage());      
   con.getHeaderFields().forEach((key,values)->
   {
    System.out.println(key+"="+values);
    System.out.println("====================");
   });      
   try(InputStream is=con.getInputStream()){System.out.println(new String(is.readAllBytes()));}
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
    ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
   
    InputStream err=con.getErrorStream();
    if(err!=null)
    {
     try(err){System.err.println(new String(is.readAllBytes()));}
     catch(Exception ex2){throw ex2;}
    }  
   } 
   con.disconnect();
  }
```

I am uploading 3 chunks. In the server side 5 packets of data are received

1. All headers. respond with 100 Continue
2. 3 Chunks. For each chunk respond with 100 Continue
3. Last Chunk[Length 0]. respond with 200 OK

Here is the Test Server

```
final class TestServer
{
 public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
 {
  try(ServerSocket socket=new ServerSocket(2000,0,InetAddress.getLocalHost()))
  {
   int count=0;
   try(Socket client=socket.accept())
   {
    int length;
    byte[] buffer=new byte[5000];
    InputStream is=client.getInputStream();
    
    OutputStream os=client.getOutputStream();
    while((length=is.read(buffer))!=-1)
    {
     System.out.println(++count);
     System.out.println(new String(buffer,0,length));
     System.out.println("==========");
  
     if(count<5)
     {
      os.write("HTTP/1.1 100 Continue\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
      os.flush();
     }
     else
     {
      os.write("HTTP/1.1 200 Done\r\nContent-Length:0\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
      os.flush();
      break;
     }   
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Output:

```
1
POST /ActionG HTTP/1.1
Expect: 100-Continue
User-Agent: Java/17.0.2
Host: 192.168.1.2:2000
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Transfer-Encoding: chunked


==========   //5 seconds later
2
5
Hello

==========   //5 seconds later
3
5
World

==========  //5 seconds later
//this and the last chunk come seperatly but with no delay
4
3
123

==========
5
0


==========
```

I have checked every Timeout Method in my Connection Object

```
System.out.println(con.getConnectTimeout());
System.out.println(con.getReadTimeout());
```

Both return 0

So where is this 5 second delay coming from?

I am using jdk 17.0.2 with windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 3 Chunks. For each chunk respond with 100 Continue

That is not how `Expect: 100-Continue` works.  Your server code is completely wrong for what you are attempting to do.  In fact, your server code is completely wrong for an HTTP server in general.  It is not even attempting to parse the HTTP protocol at all.  Not the HTTP headers, not the HTTP chunks, nothing.  Is there a reason why you are not using an actual HTTP server implementation, such as Java's own [`HttpServer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html)?

When using `Expect: 100-Continue`, the client is required to send ONLY the request headers, and then STOP AND WAIT a few seconds to see if the server sends a `100` response or not:

- If the server responds with `100`, the client can then finish the request by sending the request body, and then receive a final response.
- If the server responds with anything other than `100`, the client can fail its operation immediately without sending the request body at all.
- If no response is received, the client can finish the request by sending the request body and receive the final response.

The whole point of `Expect: 100-Continue` is for a client to ask for permission before sending a large request body.  If the server doesn't want the body (ie, the headers describe unsatisfactory conditions, etc), the client doesn't have to waste effort and bandwidth to send a request body that will just be rejected.

`HttpURLConnection` has built-in support for handling `100` responses, but see [How to wait for Expect 100-continue response in Java using HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41707775/) for caveats.  Also see [JDK-8012625: Incorrect handling of HTTP/1.1 " Expect: 100-continue " in HttpURLConnection](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8012625).

But, your server code as shown needs a major rewrite to handle HTTP *properly*, let alone handle chunked requests *properly*.

Comment: As I have said in My question.  I am experimenting with this header. My intention was never to parse anything nor to use any existing server as I wanted to anyalyze how the request and response packets looked like and so I created an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate the problem. The bug report did say resolved but I couldn't find the code on how to resolve it. If you could post that code here for debugging I will mark this as the accepted answer

Comment: The client code looks fine, for the most part. The problem is on the server side. Like I said, your server code is completely wrong for HTTP and needs to be rewritten to actually parse the HTTP protocol, you can't avoid that. Until you fix that, your 5-second delay issue is moot since you have a faulty test environment.

Answer (score 0):

So thank you @Remy Lebeau for the insights on how to properly parse this special header. I noticed after creating an basic parser and after responding properly to chunked[Transfer-Encoding:chunked header] and fixed length streaming[Content-Length header] headers that some times my client would still get stuck and wait for 5 seconds occasionally and sometimes would work with no problem.

After hours of debugging the [com.sun.www.http.HttpURLConnection](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java?msclkid=7d35d8d4a5f111eca568655e1b6b8665) class i realized Another flaw  was no longer in the server side but actually in the Client Side of the code. Especially this bit

```
con.getOutputStream().write("Hello".getBytes());
con.getOutputStream().flush();
con.getOutputStream().write("World".getBytes());
con.getOutputStream().flush();
con.getOutputStream().write("123".getBytes());
con.getOutputStream().flush();
```

I had mistakenly assumed that [getOutputStream()](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/da0da73ab82ed714dc5be94acd2f0d00fbdfe2e9/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java?msclkid=7d35d8d4a5f111eca568655e1b6b8665#L1240) in this  class would cache the outputstream returned but infact it returns an new output stream every single time.

So i had to change the code to this

```
OutputStream os=client.getOutputStream();
os.write("Hello".getBytes());
os.flush();
os.write("World".getBytes());
os.flush();
os.write("123".getBytes());
os.flush();
```

This finally solved all my problems. Works for chunked and fixed length streaming